# Register ajaxtoolkit from referenced project under same solution

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, solution

Hopefully someone can help. Our situation is this: We have a 'master' solution that contains multiple projects. All the projects are written in Visual studio 2010 using c# under the 4.0 framework. One of these projects is an extended usercontrol object. We use this extended control in every one of the other projects within the solution. The way we do this is by referencing the extended usercontrol project. now to our problem and the cause for the question.

Every project minus the extended usercontrol uses the ajaxtoolkit. We would like to remove all the individual toolkit files from each project and only have it in the extended usercontrol project. How do you go about accomplishing this? I keep getting stuck on registering the assembly but I might me barking up the wrong tree with that.